# Setting default value angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

So I have a **md-input** to save to database. I want set default value like this picture. But I tried so many times but it not ok. Please help me.

[image]

My code :

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Food" value="Sushi" [(ngModel)]="user.food">
  </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instantiate the object user.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.user.food="Sushi";
}
```